# iOS: Core Data - do I need to save the changes?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have my own "iCloud" system on my server where all data is stored in a database. The user pings this server and get new/updated data and stores it in Core data.

But I store some data temporarily in Core Data after submitting to the server (so that the user don't  have to wait until next ping to server). The server updates this data in core data when it pings the next time.

I have removed all these `[context save:&error];` for all temporarily updates/inserts and seems to work fine, but I am still wondering if I could get into some kind of trouble not saving to core data?

AND: When retrieving data from server, should I save content by every insert, or could I just save them all when records are inserted from the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you don't want to lose your data you must save. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1) to understand how Core Data works and what role `NSManagedObjectContext` is playing there - and why you need to save.

2) You don't need to save on every insert. Just save the context after the process of retrieving data from the server is finished.

Comment: Thanks! Well, It is not important if I lose my data, because it is already stored on the server, -and will be fetched some seconds later.

Comment: Okay, but when the device is restarted (or the user closes the app completely) the data won't be available any for (e.g. offline).